# TextWrapping, TextTrimming, Center Aligned and vertically stretching

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, layout, windows-phone

I have a seemingly simple layout problem in Windows Phone. The problem is illustrated in the image below:

[image: Illustration]

My requirements are as follows:

- Subtitle must always be visible, at the expense of the overflowing text of the title.
- Title and subtitle together must be vertically and horizontally centered.

When I use a `StackPanel` or auto-height `Grid` rows, the box will overflow. If I try star height rows
I can't control a large title.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a maximum width and height in your grid ?

Comment: The maximum height of the container is already there. The maximum height of the Title depends on the height of the SubTitle.

Comment: Post the relevant XAML.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <TextBlock ...>Title</TextBlock>
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" ...>SubTitle</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Found the solution, this will cover everything except the bottom element overflowing the whole screen, in my case this won't be possible. It only works if the parent container does not have infinite height provided (like a `StackPanel`).

Basically, `auto` height takes 'precedence' over `star`-height elements. This gives the bottom `TextBlock` room to choose its height, and then assigns the remaining available space to the top element.